# Solve the Integral: $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y+z} + 1}}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following integral but I am not sure where to begin.

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y+z} + 1}}dx$$

I tried substituting $u = \sqrt{x+y+z}$ but I keep getting stuck.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Does your integral make sense?

Comment: @Naive when I do the substitution?

Comment: I made a mistake but I updated the question. The original equation is a triple integral but I am not trying to determine the indefinite integral of the equation with respects to $x$.

Comment: What does not work with your substitutution? It is a good sub

Comment: $\frac{2u}{u+1}=2-\frac 2{u+1}$ and you integrate with a $\ln$.

Comment: @OmariCelestine: by this way $y+z$ can be merged in a single parameter $\lambda$ and such parameter can be readily thrown away. Your question is now equivalent to finding $\int \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{x}}$, so better to state it in this form, with some actual attempt from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured where I went wrong and thanks to those who commented I did the following:

$$
u = \sqrt{x+y+z} \\
du = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1)dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+y+z)}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{u}dx = \frac{1}{2u}dx \\
dx = 2u\ du
$$

Therefore:

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y+z}+1}dx = \int\frac{2u}{u+1}
du = \int(2-\frac{2}{u+1})du \\
= \int2\ du - 2\int\frac{1}{u+1}du \\
= 2u-2\ \ln{(u+1)} \\
= 2\sqrt{x+y+z}-2\ln(\sqrt{x+y+z}+1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y+z}+1}\rm dx$$
Let $u={x+y+z}$

And $\rm du=\rm dx$

Your integral becomes $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}+1}\rm du$$

Let $w=\sqrt{u}+1,\;\;\;\rm dw=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\rm du=\frac{1}{2(w-1)}\rm du$

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}+1}\rm du=2\int\frac{w-1}{w}dw=2(w-\ln|w|)=2(\sqrt{u}+1-\ln|\sqrt{u}+1|)=2(\sqrt{x+y+z}+1-\ln|\sqrt{x+y+z}+1|)$$